# How can I convert an element to an array?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

The array was converted to Observable using the `from` operator as shown below.

```
Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  .subscribe(onNext: {
    print($0)
  })
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

```
//Result Value
1
2
3
4
5
```

After that, I want to use several `map` or `flatMap` operators to transform, and finally I want to make an array again.
Is there an Rx operator that can create an array without using `toArray()`?

```
Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  .map { .... }
  .flatMap { .... }
  .map { .... }
  ????? -> convert to Array
  .subscribe(onNext: {
    print($0)
  })
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

```
//Expected Value
[someItem1, someItem2, ..., someItem5]
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `toArray`? That seems like exactly the thing you want.

Comment: @Sweeper It's just for learning. First, Is there another operator I don't know? Second, Is it possible to combine various operators?

Comment: FYI, because of the `flatMap` the order may be wrong... `[someItem2, someItem3, someItem1, someItem5, someItem4]`. You would have to use `concatMap` to ensure order, but that would also mean that the various effects would happen synchronously instead of in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `toArray` operator is exactly what you want given that you have used `Observable.from`. That said, you don't need to break the array up in the first place.

Also, the way you have things now, the return order is not guaranteed. If the various operations in the flatMap return at different times, the resulting array will be in a different order than the source.

If you don't break the array up with `from` then you won't need to recombine it later with `toArray` and you won't have the ordering issues.

```
Observable.just([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    .map { $0.map { /* transform each value */ } }
    .flatMap { Observable.zip($0.map { /* create an Observable using each value */ }) }
    .map { $0.map { /* transform each value */ } }
    .subscribe(onNext: {
        print($0)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```